# Resque error - /sinatra_adapter.rb:50:in `included': undefined method `before' for Sinatra::Request:Class (NoMethodError), when i start the rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, resque

I get error when I start the rails app. Just to give more information what I have done

routes.rb has

```
mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"
Gemfile has 
gem 'rails', "~> 3.2.0"
gem 'resque', :require => 'resque/server'
```

when I start rails app I get this error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/authlogic-3.1.0/lib/authlogic/
controller_adapters/sinatra_adapter.rb:50:in `included': undefined 
method `before' for Sinatra::Request:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: i found out the solution`included': undefined method `before' for Sinatra::Request:Class (NoMethodError)

The solution is to patch the last line of authlogic-3.1.0/lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/sinatra_adapter.rb from:

Sinatra::Request.send(:include, Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::SinatraAdapter::Adapter::Implementation)

to:

Sinatra::Base.send(:include, Authlogic::ControllerAdapters::SinatraAdapter::Adapter::Implementation)